# how to copy/replace/override content of multiple cells into one?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-macros, vba

I have a simple question in excel, I need to copy the content of three cells into one, for example if I enter "1" to cell A I would like to see "1" in yellow cell, or if I enter "2" into cell b I would like to see "2" in yellow cell and so on, however my inputs may not be in order, for example I may enter "3" first and "1" next. I was just wondering what formula do I need to use in excel? I need a formula that automate this process, THANKS

Thanks in advance 
[image]

Comment: and if you have "1" in A and "2" in B - what should the yellow cell display ?

Comment: so the last recently entered needs to go to yellow, for example if you enter 1 to A first and 2 to B next, yellow cell needs to display 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need something like `=Contatenate(A,B,C)` in Yellow cell

**UPDATE**:

I hope you know the basics of creating Macros. Add this macro to your workbook . This code assumes that $A$1,$A$2 and $A$3 are addresses of Blue cells and B1 is the address of Yellow cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

   If Target.Address = "$A$1" Or Target.Address = "$A$2" Or Target.Address = "$A$3" Then

       Range("B1").Value = Target.Value

   End If



    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: =Contatenate(A,B,C) will end up like "123", and I need some formula that override the yellow cell in last recently entered manner

Comment: so the last recently entered needs to go to yellow, for example if you enter 1 to A first and 2 to B next, yellow cell needs to display 2

Comment: I see! I would suggest you to use Macro that copies the value to the yellow cell and  gets executed when there is a change in blue cells.

Comment: would you please help me with that Macro!! I would truly appreciate it

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it, but I dont know any vba, how do you run or automate this process?

Comment: Which version of Excel you are using?

Comment: I honestly using the xcelsius (SAP dashboard design), excel is embedded in that software , Im assuming its using the 2007 version of excel, I need to associate this macro with those cells, I mean I need to automated somehow Thanks

Comment: If it's 2007 (I forgot what's in earlier version), follow these steps:
1. Open workbook where you want to attach the macro.
2. Press "Alt + F11" simultaneously.This will bring up a code window.
3. Double click on "Sheet1" ( unless renamed to something else). 
4. Copy the code I provided above and paste it in the empty area.
5. Hit "save" and all done!

Comment: so whenever there is a change to these cells the macro starts executing?

Comment: Yeap, the code is supposed to work exactly that way. Just give it a shot and test it.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the Macro editor? When you said you ran the code, how did you run it? You don't have to manually run it.